# Reference request: forecasting performance of subset selection versus regularization

Tags: cross-validation, references, model-selection, regularization

Imagine a simple problem where I have a $Y$ I want to predict given a large set of candidate predictors $X$.
Further assume that I am constrained to only use linear regressions.
Finally assume there is no domain knowledge that would help me select which $X$ to regress against.
I seem to have three options:

1. Use some off-the shelf penalization algorithm (say, Lasso or Elastic Nets) to make the choice for me
2. Run linear rergressions on each combination of $X$ using Cross-Validation to find their predictive error, choosing among them the one with the lowest CV error
3. Do both 1 and 2 and use nested cross-validation to select among the two.

1 is obviously easier to do but I wonder if there is any theory (or even just simulation results) that are published trying to explain when to choose one or the other.

Comment: Cross validation will be used also in case of LASSO or elastic net. The essential difference is between regularization methods and subset selection methods, see e.g. Hastie et al. "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (freely and legally available online!), Chapter 3 (and table of contents with focus on Chapter 3). Hence, consider changing the question title. See also the same source for comparison of different methods in Chapter 3.

Comment: Thanks! Actually chapter 3 is what got me into this question. There is a nice comparison between shrinkage and selection methods, but "subset selection" refers to stepwise regressions (much maligned here, as it should be) so I am not sure  how applicable they are to subset selection through cross-validation.

Comment: I think "subset selection" can refer to any strategy where variables are either *included* or *excluded* but not *included with a penalty* (which is regularization). Section 3.3.1. in Hastie et al.'s book is actually about full subset selection rather than stepwise regressions.

Comment: I recommend the following title: "Reference request: forecasting performance of subset selection versus regularization" (or similar), and adding "reference" tag.

Comment: I am not sure that 1. is "easier to do" (this is not a very specific expression...) although it is less computationally intensive for (approximately) $k>40$ variables where "leaps and bounds" for subset selection no longer works well.